# C++でのポインタから値へのアクセス方法についての質問です。

Tags: c++, ポインタ

現在、「独習C++」という書籍を使用しC++を独学で勉強しています。この書籍の中でメモリの動的確保の節の例題プログラム中で、不明点があり質問させて頂きました。以下に例題プログラムを記します。

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int *p;

p = new int[5];     //5つの整数用のメモリを割り当てる

//割り当ての成功を確認
if (!p) {
    cout << "メモリの割り当てエラー" << endl;
    return 1;
}

int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    p[i] = i;          　　　　　　　　　　//※１
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << "整数型p[" << i << "]は：";
    cout << p[i] << endl;　　　　　　　　 //※２
}

delete[] p; //メモリの解放

return 0;
}
```

プログラム中の※１,※２で、それぞれ動的に確保したint型ポインタに値の格納と値の表示が行われています。ここで、私が疑問に思っているのはなぜ間接参照演算子＊を使用せずにポインタ変数に値を代入できているのか？p[i]はアドレスを格納する変数なのではないか？ということです。私が思うに、※１の部分は

```
*(p + i) = i;
```

※２の部分は

```
cout << *(p + i) << endl;
```

と書くべきなのではないかと思います。
　しかし、実際に両方の構文を試してみると、どちらの書き方でもプログラムは正常に動作しました。何故ポインタ変数に直接的に値を格納するような書き方（p[i] = i;）ができるのか。これをどのように解釈すればよいか悩んでいます。初歩的な質問ですが、ご回答いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>   ...
>   2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets [] is a subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator []
>   is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that
>   apply to the binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>   initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer, E1[E2] designates the E2-th
>   element of E1 (counting from zero).

`p[i]`は`*(p + i)`のシンタックスシュガーで、まったく同じ意味になります。`i[p]`と書いても同じ意味になります。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a[3] = { 10, 20, 30 };
  printf("a[0] = %d\n", a[0]);
  printf("a[1] = %d\n", 1[a]);
  printf("a[2] = %d\n", *(2 + a));
  return 0;
}
```

つまり、上記のコードを実行すると次のような出力になります。

```
a[0] = 10
a[1] = 20
a[2] = 30
```

Comment: 念の為: 説明は変わらないと思いますが、この仕様は C++ ではなく C ではないでしょうか

Comment: あ、ごめんなさい、その通りです。なぜかCだと思い込んでいました

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。シンタックスシュガーだったんですね、疑問が解けてスッキリしました。因みに、C言語も少しは勉強しましたのでC言語の標準出力を使用したご説明でも理解できました。

Answer (score 2):

実は`*(p + i)`は、`p[i]`と全く同じ意味なのです。例えば、`*(p + 1)`を`*(1 + p)`と書けるように、`p[1]`も`1[p]`と書けます (あくまで文法的な話で、現実的には、このように書くメリットはないと思いますが)。

では、配列はどうなのかというと、例えば

```
int a[10];
a[1] = 10; // (1)
```

(1)のところで使われている`a`は、配列の先頭の要素のアドレス、つまり`int`のデータを指すアドレスを返すことになっています。一方、ポインタの場合は

```
int *p = new int[10];
*(p + 1) = 10; // (2)
```

`p`は`int`のポインタですので、当然`int`を指すアドレスが入っています。つまり(1)も(2)も、`int`データを指すアドレスに 1 を足して中身を参照するという、式として全く同じことをしていることになります。

配列でもポインタでも実は同じなので、`*(p + i)`は、`p[i]`と全く同じ意味になっているわけです。

Answer (score 1):

妥当な疑問です。配列は暗黙的にポインタに変換され、`p[i]` に対する代入と `*(p + i)` に対する代入は同じ意味になります。`p[i]` は「配列 `p` の `i` 番目の値」であり、`*(p + i)` は「`(p + i)` が参照する場所の値」であることに注意してください。

たとえばポインタ `p` へ確保した配列を箱の絵で表すとすると、下のような絵が描けます。

```
          +---+---+---+---+---+
int[5]    |   |   |   |   |   |   配列
          +---+---+---+---+---+
            ^           ^
            |           |
            |           |
            |           |
int*        | p+0       | p+3     ポインタ
```

(上の ASCII アートは [fredoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252000/fredoverflow) さんの[投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/5989200)を参考にしました)

参考

- [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4810668/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow
- [Pointers to arrays](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/#arrays) -- CPlusPlus.com チュートリアル